# Tango SDK overrides device theme and uses NoTitleBar theme

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, themes, google-project-tango

I'm trying to use the correct theme for each device but for some reason the Tango SDK overrides the theme and sets the NoTitleBar theme. I have tried multiple things, currently my manifest uses android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector on both the application and activity, but the game uses the NoTitleBar on a device with 5.0+. The manifest generated after build that is found on Temp/StagingArea doesn't have any line that could be changing the theme. I also exported an android project but I could not find a manifest that could be changing it. 
I'm pretty lost, I'm not really experienced on native android development so my understanding of the android project exported is minimal. 
I'm sure the issue comes from the tango SDK because I created a new android project in unity without the SDK and the correct themes appears. The moment I import the Tango SDK and build the only theme that is used is NoTitleBar.

Comment: Are you using the Unity3D SDK? If so did you have to do something special to get it to work? It crashes after about 30 seconds for everyone I have even spoken to (about 10 people so far).

Comment: I was using the Unity SDK. It was not possible to have the correct theme because the tango SDK kept overriding it. The last Tango SDK I used was the Release one and up to that point the issue was not fixed. I don't know if the issue is fixed now because I'm not currently working on a tango project. Also I cannot help you with the crash because again I don't know the status of the latest release SDK from tango.